# Sidenotes / Inline notes on nodes

Tags: 7

I was wondering, is there already a module making it possible to make inline or sidenotes/comments inside the content of a node. A good example is the notes you can add in Google Docs.

Would be great for editorial purposes!

Answer (score -1):

If I am not mistaken, it seems you want to have something like "private comments" on a node. You can find some information in the following question: [How to have separate private comments for nodes apart from the general comments?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/40355/how-to-have-separate-private-comments-for-nodes-apart-from-the-general-comments)

It mentions the [Reply](https://www.drupal.org/project/reply) module, which is still in alpha. There might be other similar modules.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean, but specifcly inline the content

Comment: This answer completely ignores the main point of the OPs question. They want to know how to add inline comments in the style of google docs. That is comments that are attached to point/piece of the content. Not a general private comment.